# Generate query expression from a string

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to map a front end query builder to a backend ORM (OrmLite).

For instance, the front end might send 3 string values: `SomeField`, `=` `foo`.

If I want to generate this query in the ORM I would do:

```
var q = db.From<MyEntity>()
          .Where(x => x.SomeField == "foo")
```

So what I need to do is come up with a way to build the where predicate from a string.

I can see the type `Where` is expecting is: `Expression<Func<MyEntity,bool>>`

So I think I need something like:

```cs
var q = db.From<MyEntity>()
          .Where(GetQueryPart("SomeField", "=", "foo");
          
//....

public Expression<Func<T,bool>> GetQueryPart<T>(string field, string queryOperator, string value)
{
    //...
    
}
```

But I am not exactly sure if this is the right approach or where exactly to start.  I had a look through the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0 and it is not clear to me how to build an expression.

Can someone give me some help with how I should approach this?

Comment: try this link => https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically

Comment: It looks like you need Dynamic LINQ: https://dynamic-linq.net/

Comment: A side note: be careful with using frontend as query source. Since anybody can build query and pass it to your API, ensure that given query won't be harmful for you *before* executing it.

Comment: @Dennis `Where` isn't a LINQ method, its a method from the ORM.  How would I use dynamic LINQ?